# improve AUCTeX macros like `\frac` and `\stackrel`

Tags: auctex, elisp-macros

While using AUCTeX, the macro `\frac` is quite intelligent that when I just type <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-m</kbd> `frac` <kbd>RET</kbd>, it will put the cursor in the first pair of braces, as

```
\frac{(cursor here)}{}
```

However, when I have selected some text and do the same, it will put the cursor at the end like

```
\frac{some text}{}(cursor here)
```

instead of putting the cursor in the second pair of braces as follows

```
\frac{some text}{(cursor here)}
```

The same thing happens to `\stackrel{}{}`. Is there a way to achieve this? Many thanks!

---

BTW

I later find out that putting the following code in the `.emacs` file helps

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (TeX-add-symbols 
               '("frac" "Numerator" "Denominator"))))
```

but this does involve more interaction with the minibuffer, which seems to be an overkill for `frac{}{}` or `\stackrel{}{}`. Besides Greek letter would not work in the minibuffer, and this turns out to have been [a problem since 1995](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/xTFubV9S4lw/Aa1-6oXX3TUJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own argument handler for `TeX-parse-macro`.
The macros together with their argument description are registered in `TeX-symbol-list`. The entries in `TeX-symbol-list` are style dependent and must be set with `TeX-add-symbols` in `LaTeX-mode-hook` for that reason.
I've stolen the method for setting up the LaTeX macros in `TeX-symbol-list` from [that answer to another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249399/2708138).

The following section from the help of `TeX-parse-macro` is important for automatically setting point after insertion of a macro:

> (TeX-parse-macro SYMBOL ARGS)
>
> How to parse TeX macros which takes one or more arguments.
>
> First argument SYMBOL is the name of the macro.
>
> If ARGS is nil, insert macro with point inside braces.
>   Otherwise, each element in ARGS should match an argument to the
>   TeX macro.  What is done depend on the type of the element:
>
> ...
>
> other symbols: Call the symbol as a function.  You can define
>     your own hook, or use one of the predefined argument hooks.  If
>     you add new hooks, you can assume that point is placed directly
>     after the previous argument, or after the macro name if this is
>     the first argument.  Please leave point located after the
>     argument you are inserting.  If you want point to be located
>     somewhere else after all hooks have been processed, set the value
>     of ‘exit-mark’.  It will point nowhere, until the argument hook
>     set it.  By convention, these hooks all start with ‘TeX-arg-’.

```el
(defvar-local TeX-arg-use-region-p nil
  "Updated in `TeX-arg-1st-of-2' with the value of `TeX-active-mark' 
and used in `TeX-arg-2nd-of-2' to detect whether to put point in between the argument braces.")

(defun TeX-arg-1st-of-2 (optional &optional prompt)
  "First of two TeX macro arguments."
  ;; Code mostly stolen from a part of `TeX-parse-macro'.
  ;; The most important modification is setting `TeX-arg-use-region-p'.
  ;; After parsing the first LaTeX-macro-argument mark is deactivated and the
  ;; information about the activation of the region is lost.
  ;; We need that information for `TeX-arg-2nd-of-2' and therefore
  ;; save it in `TeX-arg-use-region-p'.
  (if optional
      (setq TeX-group "["
        TeX-grcl "]")
    (setq TeX-group "{"
      TeX-grcl "}"))
  (insert TeX-grop)
  (if (TeX-active-mark)
      (progn
    (setq TeX-arg-use-region-p t) ;; Region is active...
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
    (insert TeX-grcl))
    (setq TeX-arg-use-region-p nil) ;; Region is not active...
    (insert TeX-grcl)
    (set-marker exit-mark (1- (point)))))

(defun TeX-arg-2nd-of-2 (optional &optional prompt)
  "Second of two TeX macro arguments."
  (insert (if optional "[]" "{}"))
  (when TeX-arg-use-region-p ;; Put mark between the braces if region was active.
    (set-marker exit-mark (1- (point)))))

;; Installation of the hack stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17249399/2708138
(defun TeX-hack-macro-args ()
  "Implement special argument handlers for TeX-macros \"frac\" and \"stackrel\"
in `TeX-symbol-list'. See `TeX-parse-macro' for more information."
  (cl-loop with args
       for macro-str in '("frac" "stackrel") do
       (TeX-add-symbols (list macro-str #'TeX-arg-1st-of-2 #'TeX-arg-2nd-of-2 '(ignore)))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'TeX-hack-macro-args)
```

Comment: This is amazing! and it is not as formidable as it looks. BTW, you solution also solves the problem for `\qitem{}{}` from the `epigraph` package, where the cursor was always put between the second pair of braces. Many thanks!

Comment: @davyjones - Thanks for pointing out the issue with `epigraph.el`.  I've [updated that file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=c03ca2c9b12091aa1d62f39f33f230746ab2fd3d) and fixed also some other issues.  It will be available with next AUCTeX release.

Comment: Note, as of Sep 13, 2020, I updated AUCTeX to version 13.0.14, I have to change the two "exit-mark" to "TeX-exit-mark" for the above code to work as before.